# Умножения двух чисел в js и вывод(поля в таблице генерируются js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться, есть таблица с полями: сумма, количество, итого. Сделал генерацию(при нажатие выпадают такие же поля). В первой строке все считает, а в других нет.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th><?php echo $text_product_name; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $text_model; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $text_price; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $text_count; ?></th>
            <th><?php echo $text_in_total; ?></th>
            <th> <a id="add_row" class="pull-left"><i  class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <th class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="product_name" required class="form-control">
            </th>
            <td class="col-sm-3">
              <input type="text" name="model_product" class="form-control">
            </td>
            <td >
              <input type="text" name="total" required class="form-control" id="i1"  onchange=simplecheckout_reload()>
            </td>
            <td >
              <img src="/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/minus.png" border="0" onclick="jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1);simplecheckout_reload('cart_value_decreased');">
              <input type="text" name="quantity" id=i2  value="1" size="1" onchange="simplecheckout_reload('cart_value_changed')" >
              <img src="/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/plus.png" border="0" onclick="jQuery(this).prev().val(~~jQuery(this).prev().val()+1);simplecheckout_reload('cart_value_increased');">
            </td>
            <td >
              <input type="number" name="oll_total" id=i3>
            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>

          </tbody>
        </table>



$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=1;
    $("#add_row").click(function(){
        $('#addr'+i).html("<td><input type='text' name='product_name"+i+"'  class='form-control'></td>" +
            "<td><input name='model_product"+i+"' type='text' class='form-control' />" +
            "</td><td><input  name='total"+i+"' type='text'  class='form-control' id='i1' onchange=simplecheckout_reload()></td>" +
            "<td><img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/minus.png' border='0' onclick=jQuery(this).next().val(~~jQuery(this).next().val()-1);onchange=simplecheckout_reload()>" +
            "<input type='text' name='quantity' id='i2'  value='1' size='1' onchange=simplecheckout_reload()>" +
            "<img src='/catalog/view/theme/default/assets/images/add/plus.png' border='0' onclick=jQuery(this).prev().val(~~jQuery(this).prev().val()+1);onchange=simplecheckout_reload();></td>" +
            "<td><input type='number' name='oll_total"+i+"' id='i3'></td>" +
            "<td><a id='delete_row' style='margin-right:30%;' class='pull-right minus'><i class='fa fa-minus' aria-hidden='true'></i></a></td></td>");

        $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr'+(i+1)+'"></tr>');
        i++;
    });
    $("#delete_row").click(function(){
        if(i > 1 ){
            $("#addr"+(i-1)).html('');
            i--;
        }
    });
});





 jQuery(document).on('click', '.minus', function(){
  jQuery( this ).closest( 'tr' ).remove(); 
 });



function simplecheckout_reload(){
  var n1=document.getElementById('i1').value;
  var n2=document.getElementById('i2').value;
  document.getElementById('i3').value=Number(n1)*Number(n2);
}
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` - находит один-единственный элемент на странице. Вот почему атрибут `id` должен быть уникальным.

Comment: Так что никак не получиться сделать типа id = 'i "+i+"'

Comment: может есть какой то другой способ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById` - находит один-единственный элемент на странице. Вот почему атрибут `id` должен быть уникальным.

Можно обойтись вообще без `id` для инпутов:

```
function simplecheckout_reload(element){
  var row = $(element).closest("tr");

  var n1 = row.find("input[name='total']").val();
  var n2 = row.find("input[name='quantity']").val();

  row.find("input[name='oll_total']").val(Number(n1) * Number(n2));
}
```

`onchange='simplecheckout_reload(this);'`

Comment: Подскажите что не работает, когда я вставляю `onchange='simplecheckout_reload(this);'` в саму форму то работает, а когда вставляю где   генерируется html не просчитывает, console.log(row); показывает все ok, что не так  не могу понять можете объяснить или показать, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: вот что приходит ` value:25.6
valueAsDate:null
valueAsNumber:NaN` это когда генерируется `([prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: input#i1.form-control, selector: "input[name='oll_total']"])`

Comment: все разобрался не работает потому что  `name='oll_total"+i+"'` убрал все зароботоло